# Cloud Firestore Offline Encryption

Tags: firebase, encryption, google-cloud-firestore

Does anyone know if the local cache of the Firebase Cloud Firestore is encrypted at rest on the clients? I want to temporarily store sensitive details (think payment details) in the datastore until network connectivity becomes available and I can fire off some cloud functions and dispose of the data. I could go about encrypting the data before it is stored, but then that necessitates the need to rotate keys etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The google group responded, and the answer is no. The store is not encrypted on the device. This facilitated the need for encryption prior to storing the data.

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/fa4RygAeFJg